# How can I easily set up an email server for development purposes?

Tags: virtualization, smtp, email-server, imap

I'm developing a webmail UI, but I can't use Mailgun or my Gmail account, as I need public and shared namespaces.

I tried to install Dovecot, but it required tons of configuration.

Is there a server that is easy to configure and run? Or maybe an image I can drop into Virtualbox that has all the work already done?

Answer (score 2):

[iRedMail](http://www.iredmail.org/index.html) is also very quick to configure.

Answer (score 1):

There is a [VMware Virtual Appliance Marketplace](http://www.vmware.com/appliances/directory/) containing ready-to-go virtual machines for many purposes. There is (for example) already a [Zimbra VM](http://www.vmware.com/appliances/directory/va/663933). Other appliances are also there...

Comment: Looks promising, but every time I see one that might work, I hit a login/trial page. Any specific one that looks good?

Answer (score 1):

I have found iRedMail and [this tutorial from Rackspace](http://www.rackspace.com/knowledge_center/index.php/Ubuntu_9.04_-_iRedMail_Installation) a very good combination to get mail up and running very quickly.  It is a good solution if you need to set up a server so that you can send and receive email to and from your server, with multiple domain names/aliases, as well as having a lightweight web front-end to access mail.  You can still use normal email clients to access your email as well.

The guide is very Ubuntu/Debian biased.

Answer (score 0):

[Zimbra Open Source Edition](http://www.zimbra.com/products/zimbra-open-source.html) is a quick solution for what you're asking. Also see the recommendations at:

https://serverfault.com/questions/316391/which-is-the-easiest-to-configure-mta-pop3-imap-solution